# Least squares / residual sum of squares in closed form

Tags: least-squares, matrices

In finding the Residual Sum of Squares (RSS) We have:

\begin{equation}
\hat{Y} = X^T\hat{\beta}
\end{equation}

where the parameter $\hat{\beta}$ will be used in estimating the output value of input vector $X^T$ as $\hat{Y}$

\begin{equation}
RSS(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - x_i^T\beta)^2
\end{equation}

which in matrix form would be

\begin{equation}
RSS(\beta) = (y - X \beta)^T (y - X \beta)
\end{equation}

differentiating w.r.t $\beta$ we get

\begin{equation}
X^T(y - X\beta) = 0
\end{equation}

My question is how is the last step done? How did the derivative get the last equation?

Comment: It should say $\hat Y=X\hat\beta$, with no transpose. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This equation was in Section 3.2 of The Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie, et al

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is standard multiplication and differentiation rules for matrices.

We have

$$RSS(\beta) = (y - X \beta)^T (y - X \beta) = (y^T - \beta^TX^T)(y - X \beta) \\
=y^Ty-y^TX \beta-\beta^TX^Ty+\beta^TX^TX \beta$$

Then
$$\frac {\partial RSS(\beta)}{\partial \beta} = -X^Ty-X^Ty+2X^TX\beta$$

the last term because the matrix $X^TX$ is symmetric.

So
$$\frac {\partial RSS(\beta)}{\partial \beta} =0 \Rightarrow -2X^Ty+2X^TX\beta =0 \Rightarrow -X^Ty+X^TX\beta = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow X^T(-y + X\beta) = 0\Rightarrow X^T(y-X\beta)=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the derivation This might be helpful for the newbies for [derivative of a quadratic form](http://michael.orlitzky.com/articles/the_derivative_of_a_quadratic_form.php)

Comment: Yes, that could helpful.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Randal J. Barnes, Matrix Differentiation](http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf), Prop. 7, if $\alpha=y^TAx$ where $y$ and $x$ are vectors and $A$ is a matrix, we have
$$\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x}=y^TA\text{ and }\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial y}=x^TA^T$$
(the proof is very simple). Also according to his Prop. 8, if $\alpha=x^TAx$ then
$$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}=x^T(A+A^T).
$$
Therefore in Alecos's solution above, I would rather write
$$
\frac{\partial\mathrm{RSS}(\beta)}{\partial\beta}=-y^TX-y^TX+\beta^T(X^TX+XX^T)
$$
where the last term is indeed $2\beta^TX^TX$ since $X^TX$ is symmetric and hence $X^TX=XX^T$. This gives us an equation
$$
(y^T+b^TX^T)X=0
$$
which provides the same result as in Alecos's answer, if we take the transpose of both sides. I guess Alecos has used a different definition of matrix differentiation than Barnes, but the final result is, of course, correct.

Comment: Just saw this. Helpful. Indeed, sometimes differentiation for matrices is defined differently, but leading to the same results.

Comment: +1 for including the matrix differentiation properties and link to a review.

Comment: why is $X^\text{T}X$ symmetric

Answer (score 1):

This is a repeat of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2165835/81560).

Let 
$$\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\vdots \\
y_N
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1p} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2p} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x_{N1} & x_{N2} & \cdots & x_{Np}
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
\vdots \\
b_p
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
Then $\mathbf{X}\beta \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and
$$\mathbf{X}\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{1j} \\
\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{2j} \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{Nj}
\end{bmatrix} \implies \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 - \sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{1j} \\
y_2 - \sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{2j} \\
\vdots \\
y_N - \sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{Nj}
\end{bmatrix} \text{.}$$
Therefore,
$$(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^{T}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta) = \|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta \|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)^2\text{.} $$ 
We have, for each $k = 1, \dots, p$,
$$\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_k} = 2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)(-x_{ik}) = -2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ik}\text{.}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \beta} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_1} \\
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_2} \\
\vdots \\
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_p}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=  \begin{bmatrix}
-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i1} \\
-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i2} \\
\vdots \\
-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ip}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=  -2\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i1} \\
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i2} \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ip}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=  -2\mathbf{X}^{T}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: can you join this [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69336/elements-of-statistical-learning) please?