# Differentiation with respect to a matrix (residual sum of squares)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I've *never* heard of differentiating with respect to a matrix. Let $\mathbf{y}$ be a $N \times 1$ vector, $\mathbf{X}$ be a $N \times p$ matrix, and $\beta$ be a $p \times 1$ vector. Then the residual sum of squares is defined by
$$\text{RSS}(\beta) = \left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta\right)^{T}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta\right)\text{.}$$
*The Elements of Statistical Learning*, 2nd ed., p. 45, states that when we differentiate this with respect to $\beta$, we get
$$\begin{align}
&\dfrac{\partial\text{RSS}}{\partial \beta} = -2\mathbf{X}^{T}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta\right) \\
&\dfrac{\partial^2\text{RSS}}{\partial \beta\text{ }\partial \beta^{T}} = 2\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
I mean, I could look at $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ as "constants" and $\beta$ as a variable, but it's unclear to me where the $-2$ in $\dfrac{\partial\text{RSS}}{\partial \beta}$ comes from, and why we would use $\beta^T$ for the second partial.

Any textbooks that cover this topic would be appreciated as well.

*Side note*: this is not homework. Please note that I graduated with an undergrad degree only, so assume that I've seen undergraduate real analysis, abstract algebra, and linear algebra for my pure mathematics background.

Comment: RSS is being viewed as a function of the vector $\beta$. In this situation, the derivative with respect to $\beta$ will be a linear functional which takes a vector $h$ of the same size as $\beta$ and returns the number $-2(y-X\beta)^T Xh$, except that the text evidently prefers to view it as a function of $h^T$ as follows: $h^T \mapsto h^T[-2 X^T(y-X\beta)]$. This is a bit of an abstract view of multivariable calculus. You need to find a book where the derivative of a mapping at a point is considered a linear function, and get used to that formalism.

Comment: I've had a look and haven't been able to find any sources for this in English with a reasonable number of examples of these calculations. For the theory, you can see *Mathematical Analysis II* by Zorich or the more comprehensive *Foundations of Modern Analysis* by Dieudonné. I'm sure there must be textbooks out there with exercises on these things, but I don't know any. Generally, a textbook with a chapter on "differential calculus in Banach spaces" would address this in theory, but some will be better than others for sample calculations.

Comment: @user208259 - Thank you, I appreciate the effort. I've looked up what a Banach space is and... I only have an undergrad degree, so I haven't seen functional analysis at all. I think I *may* have managed to find something in a not-so-well-known text (*Matrix Algebra* by Gentle). It is, however, a dense read.

Comment: In principle, it doesn't need to be a Banach space for what you're doing. It's just that if a book does present differential calculus in that context, then it has to talk about it in terms of linear mappings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow, I asked this two years ago!

Since then, I've learned what the notation means for quick computational purposes.

Let 
$$\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\vdots \\
y_N
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1p} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2p} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x_{N1} & x_{N2} & \cdots & x_{Np}
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
\vdots \\
b_p
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
Then $\mathbf{X}\beta \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and
$$\mathbf{X}\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{1j} \\
\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{2j} \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{Nj}
\end{bmatrix} \implies \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 - \sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{1j} \\
y_2 - \sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{2j} \\
\vdots \\
y_N - \sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{Nj}
\end{bmatrix} \text{.}$$
Therefore,
$$(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^{T}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta) = \|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta \|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)^2\text{.} $$ 
We have, for each $k = 1, \dots, p$,
$$\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_k} = 2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)(-x_{ik}) = -2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ik}\text{.}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \beta} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_1} \\
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_2} \\
\vdots \\
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_p}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=  \begin{bmatrix}
-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i1} \\
-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i2} \\
\vdots \\
-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ip}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=  -2\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i1} \\
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i2} \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ip}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=  -2\mathbf{X}^{T}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
For the second partial, as one might guess:
$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \beta^{T}} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_1} &
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_2} &
\cdots &
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_p}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= -2\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i1} &
\cdots &
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ip}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$
Now we "stack" to take the partial with respect to $\beta$:
$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial^2\text{RSS}}{\partial \beta\text{ }\partial\beta^{T}} &= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\left(\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \beta^{T}}  \right) \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
-2\cdot \dfrac{\partial}{\partial b_1}\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i1} &
\cdots &
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ip} 
\end{bmatrix} \\
\vdots \\
-2\cdot \dfrac{\partial}{\partial b_p}\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i1} &
\cdots &
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ip} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
-2\begin{bmatrix}
-\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i1}^2 & \cdots & -\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i1}x_{ip} 
\end{bmatrix} \\
\vdots \\
-2\begin{bmatrix}
-\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i1}x_{ip} & \cdots & -\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{ip}^2
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 2\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Best and most clear explanation I have ever searched on line.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Many thanks for that, the explanation really is quite intuitive after having spent some time learning about partial derivatives. However,  I am a bit confused: where is the intercept term ($\beta_0$)? Looks like it is just disregarded?

Comment: @Sejmou  You can simply modify the notation to use $\beta_0$ in place of $b_1$, $\beta_1$ in place of $b_2$, etc., and make the first row of $\mathbf{X}$ a row of ones. The notation above is just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @Sejmou Correction (that's what I get for doing math too early): it should be the first **column** of $\mathbf{X}$, rather than the first row.

Answer (score 8):

So, what you have here is basically a functional. You're inputting a matrix ($\mathbf{X}$) and a couple vectors ($\mathbf{y}$ and $\beta$), then combining them in such a way that the output is just a number. So, what we need here is called a functional derivative.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $\gamma$ be an arbitrary $p \times 1$ vector, then
$$\frac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \beta} \equiv \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \Big((\epsilon \gamma^T)^{-1}\big(\text{RSS}(\beta + \epsilon \gamma) - \text{RSS}(\beta)\big) \Big).
$$

We're adding a small, arbitrary vector to $\beta$ and then seeing how that changes $\text{RSS}$. We 'divide' out this arbitrary vector at the end, and I've used the transpose here because $\beta$ and $\gamma$ enter the original functional as multiplication from the right, so coming from the left we use the transpose. All that is left is to evaluate these expressions.

$$\text{RSS}(\beta+\epsilon\gamma) = \left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}(\beta+\epsilon\gamma)\right)^{T}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}(\beta+\epsilon\gamma)\right) = \left((\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^{T}-(\mathbf{X}\epsilon\gamma)^T)\right)\left((\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)-\mathbf{X}\epsilon\gamma)\right)
$$
$$= (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^{T}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)-(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^{T}\mathbf{X}\epsilon\gamma-(\mathbf{X}\epsilon\gamma)^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)+(\mathbf{X}\epsilon\gamma)^T\mathbf{X}\epsilon\gamma
$$
$$=\text{RSS}(\beta)- \epsilon \big((\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^{T}\mathbf{X}\gamma+(\mathbf{X}\gamma)^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)\big) + \epsilon^2 (\mathbf{X}\gamma)^T\mathbf{X}\gamma
$$
So,
$$\frac{\text{RSS}(\beta + \epsilon \gamma) - \text{RSS}(\beta)}{\epsilon \gamma^T} = \frac{-\big((\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^{T}\mathbf{X}\gamma+(\mathbf{X}\gamma)^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)\big) + \epsilon (\mathbf{X}\gamma)^T\mathbf{X}\gamma}{\gamma^T}.
$$

The third term, than, does not survive in the limit and we are left with
$$\frac{-\big((\gamma^T \mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta))+(\gamma^T \mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta))^T\big)}{\gamma^T}
$$

However, since both of these terms are just $1 \times 1$ matrices, A.K.A. scalars, then the term and its transpose are equal and we are left with
$$\frac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \beta} = -2 \mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)
$$

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help on Chat! :)

Comment: There's also this (simpler) answer

http://math.stackexchange.com/a/757130