# Differentiating wrt to a transposed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I am following the derivation in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111504/differentiation-with-respect-to-a-matrix-residual-sum-of-squares).  So we have:
$$\begin{align}
\text{RSS}(\beta) & = (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta) & (1)
\end{align}$$

Differentiate w.r.t to $\beta$ and $\beta^T$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
&\dfrac{\partial\text{RSS}}{\partial\beta} = -2X^{T}(y-X\beta)  &&& (2)\\
&\dfrac{\partial^2\text{RSS}}{\partial \beta\text{ }\partial \beta^{T}} = 2X^{T}X\text{.} &&& (3)
\end{align}$$

I understand the first differentiation from this [explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756679/least-squares-residual-sum-of-squares-in-closed-form/757130#757130).  However, I do not know how you can go from $(2)$ to $(3)$.  Could someone explain?

Also, how do you get this?
$$y^TX\beta=\beta^TX^Ty$$

TIA!

---

For the second part, they are each other's transpose:

$$(y^TX\beta)^T=((y^TX)\beta)^T=\beta^T(y^TX)^T=\beta^T(X^Ty)=\beta^TX^Ty$$

And since they are scalar, we have have the equality.

Comment: I believe $\beta^\intercal X^\intercal y$ is a matrix of type $(1,1)$ (canonically identified with a real number), so equal to its transpose.

Comment: In another word, scalar?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the $-2X^\top y$ term, your question essentially boils down to "why is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} A \beta = A$ true?" where $A=X^\top X$. You can check this by thinking about the matrix multiplication $A\beta$ and taking partial derivatives with respect to each $\beta_i$.

Comment: Actually, it's about a $\dfrac{\partial\text{}}{\partial\beta^T}$ differentiation.  It's the transpose that bugs me.

Comment: @CaTx (3) is the Hessian which has elements $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \beta_i \partial \beta_j}$. The gradient has elements $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_i}$, so taking each element of the gradient and applying all the partial derivatives (i.e. compute the Jacobian of the Hessian) will give you the elements of the Hessian. Don't worry too much about the notation $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \beta \partial \beta^\top}$.

Comment: Is there any document you can give me that would explain this Hessian operation in details?

Comment: @CaTx For the sake of understanding, start by looking at the [definition of the Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) as a matrix of partial derivatives (and similarly, the gradient is also a vector of partial derivatives) and think about how to compute each partial derivative.

Comment: Thank you!  You have been great help.